# creating dynamic sub domain using php

Tags: php, dns

My code executing fine but folder and sub domain not created. Please tell where exactly i am doing mistake.

```
function create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain)
{
    $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/subdomains/" . $subDomain;

    $openSocket = fsockopen('78.46.111.226',2082);
    if(!$openSocket) {
        return "Socket error";
        exit();
    }

    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Host:$rootDomain\r\n";

    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
    while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
    }
    fclose($openSocket);

    $newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";

    return "Created subdomain $newDomain";

}
```

Hoping for the quickest reply
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to create dynamic folder for that, you can use htaccess batter than that.

Try below htaccess code for the same :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
$openSocket = fsockopen('78.46.111.226',2082);
```

with

```
$openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
```

and replace

```
$buildHeaders .= "Host:$rootDomain\r\n";
```

with

```
$buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
```